# Custom input Tag Helper in asp.net vnext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net 5 (vnext) to a new project and also using the tag helper approach.

By my input elements need a lot of div elements around them to display correctly.

I can do this manually, but it will be very bad for readability.

How can I extend an input tag helper, so I can get something like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
   <input .....>
</div>
```

using only an input element in my razor view:

```
<input asp-for....>
```

thanks.

Comment: I think that this will help you, https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/12/14/tag-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that using `PreElement` and `PostElement` solves the problem.

In my TagHelper custom class:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    ....
    output.PreElement.SetHtmlContent("<div class='row'><div class='form-control'>");
    output.PostElement.SetHtmlContent("</div></div>");
}
```